# codeigniter session is deleted automaticly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have several projects of codeigniter with the use of tank auth and ion auth.

I notice now that after users login, in the first page they move they are logged out...

I cant find why is that, and this is not only on one project so it couldn't be my code.

any advice?

and it happends only on chrome....

Comment: How do you expect us to answer without some code. "I cant find why is that, and this is not only on one project so it couldn't be my code." means nothing to us. Let us decide whatever its your code or it is a bug.

Comment: nothing to post, I did a fresh install of codeigniter and the sessions doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

My friend had a similar issue and solved it by setting `$config['cookie_secure']`   to FALSE. Basically, since he was not using https, cookies were not created.